# Can't set background color

Tags: java, jframe

For some reason my background just doesn't turn blue. Does anyone know how to solve this with keeping everything inside?

I've been trying to fix this for ages already, but nothing works apparantly..

```
public static void window() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sharp");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(
        new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    JPanel b = new JPanel();
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Hello, World!", JLabel.CENTER);
    label2.setAlignmentY(0);
    label2.setAlignmentX(0);
    label2.setText("<html>Made by Julian</html>");
    JPanel a = new JPanel();
    b.add(label2);
    a.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    a.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850, 500));
    a.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(850, 850)); // set max = pref


    JToggleButton tb = new JToggleButton("SHARP Instructions");
    tb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JToggleButton btn =  (JToggleButton) e.getSource();


            if(btn.isSelected()) {
                Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
                try {
                    d.browse(new URI("https://pastebin.com/nDdGZ0cJ"));
                } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        }
    }); 

    frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    a.add(tb);

   // JPanel b = new JPanel();

    frame.add(a, new GridBagConstraints());
    frame.getContentPane().add(a);
    frame.getContentPane().add(b);
    //frame.getContentPane().add(b);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `JPanel a` is on top of your `JFrame`, so just:

`a.setBackground(Color.BLUE);` will fix it.

Comment: and what about images? if i try to add one every time its going ABOVE th ebutton... Is that also because of something like that?

Comment: You should read a bit about how layouts work https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html. If you run in to a problem, you can post a new question.